# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code written:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './toolbar.css';
class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  createToolbar(container) {
    return container;
  }
  getCreateToolbar() {
    const { createToolbar } = this.props;
    return createToolbar ? createToolbar : this.createToolbar;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { editor } = this.props;
    const createToolbar = this.getCreateToolbar();
    const toolbar = createToolbar(this.toolbarContainer);
    editor.add(toolbar);
  }
  render() {
    return (<div className="toolbar" ref={el => { this.toolbarContainer = el; }}>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//at.alicdn.com/t/font_598462_3xve1872wizzolxr.css" />
      <i data-command="undo" className="command iconfont icon-undo" title="Annuler"></i>
      <i data-command="redo" className="command iconfont icon-redo" title="Prêt"></i>
      <span className="separator"></span>
      <i data-command="copy" className="command iconfont icon-copy-o" title="Copy"></i>
      <i data-command="paste" className="command iconfont icon-paster-o" title="Paste"></i>
      <i data-command="delete" className="command iconfont icon-delete-o" title="Delete"></i>
    </div>);
  }
}
Toolbar.propTypes = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-typos
  createToolbar: PropTypes.func,
  editor: PropTypes.object
};
export default Toolbar;
```

I am trying to add a `toolbar` to editor.
the code compile successfully but in navigateur chose this error.

In the navigateur page erreur:

```
react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
at Toolbar.componentDidMount (Toolbar.js:16)
at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:20663)
.....
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you paste your parent code as well? In this code your `editor ` prop is undefined

Comment: Might be helpful, seem's someone completed what you are attempting. https://github.com/antvis/g6-editor/blob/master/demos/rc-components/Toolbar.jsx